# How to get the css property from external css file if the inline style is applied?

Tags: jquery, css

How to get the css property from external source using js/jquery if the inline style is applied to the same element?
Example:

```
<div id="my" style='left:100px'>some content</div>
<style>
    #my{left:250px;}
</style>
```

I want to return 250px, if that's possible without removing the inline style?

Comment: You are specifically getting the stylings applied to an ID, correct? Because there's an easier way if you're talking about an element that does not have to be unique.

Comment: #my{left:250px!important;} will override inline style.

Answer (score 3):

Are you able to alter the markup after the page loads? If so, I would use jQuery to change the style attribute to an empty value. Then I would get the left value via jQuery.

```
var my = $('#my');
my.attr('style','');
var position = my.position();
alert(position.left);
```

or if you don't want to cache the var:

```
$('#my').attr('style','');
alert($('#my').position().left);
```

Comment: This will work.  I was already working on a Fiddle for this (http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/pRetH/).

Comment: This works, but it might cause a slight "blink" between positions if you're going to restore the contents of `style` afterwards.

Comment: Actually i am adding that inline-style after the page load, so i can get the css value before that function and store it in the global var. But i was just wondering if that's possible to achieve without that extra var? Your code is good , but i would stick to my current code...

Comment: You could do it without the var. Just good practice in terms of speed to cache the object. That way, jQuery only has to search for the element once.

Comment: Bravo Moettinger, that's it! If you want, write that as an answer so i can confirm it...

Comment: K. I added the non-var version.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to just remove the inline style for a moment, reading it out and putting it back.

You won't see any graphical changes to the element while the style is taken away. It just goes too fast.

http://jsfiddle.net/fp7UB/

```
function readstyle() {
    var el = document.getElementById('my');
    var attr = el.getAttribute('style');
    el.setAttribute('style', '');
    var val = el.offsetLeft;
    el.setAttribute('style', attr);
    return val;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to download the `.css` file via AJAX (you can use the easy-to-use **jQuery** `$.get()`), and then parse it using [JSCSPP](http://glazman.org/JSCSSP/) or something equivalent ([another parser which is written in jQuery)](http://bililite.com/blog/2009/01/16/jquery-css-parser/). While this might be considered an overkill, it gives you the advantage that you can access all the rules after one grabbing process.